# Multiple return types from single scipy function

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

I'm using the scipy library for calculating [t-tests](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html) and I'm trying to understand why there would be multiple return types from a single function call. It caught me out, as in different environments, it returns different objects.

For instance, locally I get:

```
rvs1 = stats.norm.rvs(loc=5,scale=10,size=500)
rvs2 = stats.norm.rvs(loc=5,scale=10,size=500)
stats.ttest_ind(rvs1,rvs2)
(0.26833823296239279, 0.78849443369564776)
stats.ttest_ind(rvs1,rvs2, equal_var = False)
(0.26833823296239279, 0.78849452749500748)
```

which is what it shows on the example on their website. However, when it runs on CircleCI (a continuous integration service) in a virtual machine I get:

```
rvs1 = stats.norm.rvs(loc=5,scale=10,size=500)
rvs2 = stats.norm.rvs(loc=5,scale=10,size=500)
stats.ttest_ind(rvs1,rvs2)
(array(-1.603223040889008), 0.10920183417176929)
stats.ttest_ind(rvs1,rvs2, equal_var = False)
(array(-1.603223040889008), 0.10920185489799822)
```

where the first element of the tuple is now an array!

Why have these different return types that seem almost interchangeable? Is it for backwards compatibility (although both server and locally were running 0.14.0)? How could the environment have this effect?

I eventual solved it by running:

```
np.array(stats.ttest_ind(rvs1,rvs2))
```

which converted it into a single array of two elements.

As interested as I am in a better solution to this issue, I'd like to get to the bottom of why there are different return types from the single function and why it was designed as such?

Comment: Show us the `numpy` and `python` versions as well as the `scipy` ones.  This may be a side effect of some other code change.

Comment: python: 2.7.11 & numpy: 1.8.1

Comment: Like hpauj mentioned, tell us the scipy versions running on both the local machine as well as on the remote. There will most likely be a difference in both. Between those two versions, a change was most likely made to alter the output types.

Comment: I'm getting the `array())` expression - with numpy 1.8 and 1.9, scipy 1.13 and 1.14 (and py2 and py3).

Comment: The current `stats.stats.py` file (on Github) shows some major reorganization of these `ttest...` functions (compared to my versions).  For one thing, the function now returns a `namedtuple`.  You many need to dig into the code history and issues to determine when/where the relevant changes occurred (and why).

Comment: @oliverW in my OP I stated that they are both running the same scipy versions. This is where my confusion came from. I'm going to have a look into the github repo now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To always ensure I had a consistent output to this, I wrapped it in a numpy array and flattened it:

`np.array(stats.ttest_ind(rvs1.values, rvs2.values)).flatten()`

which will return:

`[0.26833823296239279, 0.78849443369564776]`

regardless of the version